# How to bypass "Choose an app for the USB device" on Android device

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

When I plug an external device into my Android phone via USB, it gives a pop-up that says "Choose an app for the USB device" with 2 app options to choose from. Is there a way to bypass this and automatically open a pre-set app? Thanks!

Comment: doesn't an option appear under the apps ? (just once , Always) before you choose the app to open

Comment: Hi Bilal, yes those options do appear but is there a way for users to bypass that and not go through that even once?

Comment: you have to press the "always" option  once then it wouldn't appear again but you can't bypass it from the start because it's a defualt setting in the phone to ask you which app you want to run